# Redis Error - TypeError: substr(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, Credis_Client given in

Tags: magento2.4

So my site has been down for a day now caused by an issue with Redis, my host is continually stopping it and restarting things to get it back online but this does not last long a few hours at best, then it crashes again, the host has sent me this:

this is due to an coding error within your application and not with redis itself, the error shown below shows you are passing an instance of "Credis_Client" to the substr() PHP function when this function expects a String;

TypeError: substr(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, Credis_Client given in /var/www/vhosts/sparetoolparts.co.uk/htdocs/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis/Cm/Cache/Backend/Redis.php:1309

I have no clue what this means, I was hoping someone here could provide some feedback so I can pass it onto my host and developers

Comment: Could you post TEXT of last 100 lines of your ERROR log?  We may see the offending non-string code that is causing the problem.